# how to add required attribute only if another input is not empty with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list inside a form, so that in every list item there are 2 inputs.

I want that when the form submitted, if one of the 2 inputs that i have on the same list is not empty, they both should be fulfilled  (required attribute), but if on other list item the 2 inputs are empty, send them as they are.

Here is an example of only one list item :

```
<form class="settings-form quick-reports">
    <ul class="report-list">
        <li class="report-list-li"> 
            <span class="report-num">Report 01</span> 
            <div class="settings-name-fields">
                <label for="website-name1" class="report-name">Name</label>
                <input class="website-input" type="text" id="website-name1">
            </div>
            <div class="settings-url-fields">
                <label for="website-url1" class="report-url">URL</label>
                <input class="url-input" type="url">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Tought about something like that:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
if($(input1).val() !== ""){
    $('input1').prop('required', true);
    $('input2').prop('required', true);
}
});
```

But I don't know how to accomplish that and make it fit for every list item on my list

My whole fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vvLkwajo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

Using [**`.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    // remove required property in case that some fields were modified before click
    $('.report-list input').prop('required', false).each(function(){
        !$(this).val() || $(this).closest('li').find('input').prop('required', true);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kcLyjpn/)

---

Or [**`.filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    $('.report-list input').prop('required', false).filter(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).closest('li').find('input').prop('required', true);
});
```

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fku3ysh1/)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice not to use the property `required` here, first of all this property does not work in all browsers (IE just ignores it for example), second, it might be that setting it on submit might be too late.

I would use something like this:

```
if($(input1).val() == "" && $(input2).val()==""){
    //handle case and show error message
    alert("Either input one or input2 needs a value");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //make sure the form is not submitted
}
```